# How to store user data into Firbase database after authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm new to android studio and firebase and i'm doing an android application where i am required to create user roles to see different features in the app (client & trainer). I know that this isn't available through firebase authentication so i was advised to insert the user details into the database and assign/access roles from there. I'm trying to make the database look something like this...

[How i'm trying to structure the real-time database (manually added to database)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7qyC.png)

//Where 'User1Email' can be either email of user or user id (as i think you cannot include @ into database)

However my code seems to be crashing the application. The way i've tried to update the data to the database in my .java file looks like this..

```
//ESTABLISH THE CONNECTIONS TO DATABASE AND GET TE USER ID
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("users");


        EditText emailField = findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText passwordField = findViewById(R.id.password);

        //Get email and password from text views
        final String email = emailField.getText().toString();
        final String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

         mRef.child("password").setValue(password);
         mRef.child("role").setValue("Trainer");

// I DID ALSO TRY THIS BUT UID STAYS UNDERLINED RED-  mRef.child(uid).child("password").setValue(password);
```

ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finalyearapp, PID: 13903
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.finalyearapp.SignUpActivity.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:53)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: What's an error?

Comment: Please add error logcat to you question. Also I did something like you but instead of Real-time database i used Cloud Firestore, do you have needs with realtime database?

Comment: How to structure you data https://youtu.be/haMOUb3KVSo

Comment: @Gabriel14 should i just copy & paste it to the bottom of the question or screenshot it?

Comment: Copy and paste it. Code screenshots are pretty bad on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gabriel14 i have added the error code, hope that is clearer now. And there is no specific reason to use the real-time database over cloud , that's just how we were briefly shown in lectures

Comment: It seems that the instance of the user is null. Are you sure that you log in with an account before this code?

Comment: @Gabriel14 oh that makes sense, no i haven't. I'm trying to do this during the onClick when signing up. Is there a way to get the user id for the database when when the account is being created?

Comment: I'm going to write an answer where i explain that

Comment: @Ezan okay, i wrote it. I have another doubt, why you save password on Realtime DB?

Comment: @Gabriel14 yea that's something i have now changed and is n longer needed for DB simplicity and overall security

Comment: ok i deleted it in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must authenticate an user before getting his instance.

To make sure that user is logged before doing anything, call `getCurrentUser()` method in 
`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` (if you are using email and password authentication).

First of all create and initialize a Firebase Auth object :

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then when you want to **sign up** (supposed with a button) call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method :

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //Successfully created user
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("users");


                EditText emailField = findViewById(R.id.email);

                //Get email from EditText
                final String email = emailField.getText().toString();

                mRef.child("role").setValue("Trainer");
            } else {
                //User not created,

                //Print exception
                Log.e("Sign up", task.getException().getMessage())

                //Write your code to handle user creation fail
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want to learn more of Firebase Authentication, look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

***Remember that this solution is only for users creation.***

Hope it helps! Write a comment to more explanation or if you have another question!

Comment: Funny story, i already had an `onCompleteListener` case but i declared the `uid` and its `.getCurrentUser` outside because i didn't know you can do it inside. Been at it for 2 days now but thanks, your help really cleared things up! :)

Comment: Unrelated question but do you know if it is possible to sign users up through referral with Firebase?

Comment: What do you mean with "referral"? Something like a "friend code"?

Comment: Kinda like a friend code. So for this project i wanted the Trainer to send a link or "referral" code to the Client, so that would be the only way they could create an account

Comment: Do you think dynamic links would be a good idea or has the capabilities for this?

Comment: Honestly if you want to create something like a "course" and make that the trainer can "invite" people with his own code, I suggest you to create a univocal random code for every trainer when he creates his own account and let normal users to subscribe using that code.

Answer (score 0):

In your database you have `Users` node with a capital `U`, therefore you should change the following:

```
 final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("users");
```

into this:

```
final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("Users");
```

Also you need to add a `child()` to include the `userId`:

```
final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("Users").child(uid);
mRef.child("password").setValue(password);
mRef.child("role").setValue("Trainer");
```

Then you will have:

```
Users
  userId
     password : password
     role     : Trainer
```

Comment: Thank you however i still seem to get the error code  in the question

Comment: the user is null, did you authenticate the user?

Comment: No i haven't cause this is in the signup activity whlst making an account. Do you know how to get a user id when creating an account?